# Use Office.js APIs from outside an Office Add in

Tags: excel-addins, office-js, word-addins

In the Office.js docs one reads the following about the new ExecuteAsync() method/pattern:

> "This also allows us to use the same APIs even outside of an Excel add-
>   in.  Imagine, for example, that you wanted to call Excel APIs against an > Excel workbook stored in OneDrive, but you wanted to do so from a stand-> alone web application, rather than one running inside Office 2016 for 
>   Windows or Office Online.  This async model lends itself well to that 
>   capability."

Nevertheless, I wasn't able to find any explanation on how to implement such functionality in a standalone web application. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referring to the new Excel REST API. Please see the documentation here: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel

Excel is so far the only Office host to support REST APIs, with the exception of OneNote's REST APIs which are independent from the Office.js effort.

Comment: Anything else in development?  I was really hoping for a solution that combines the power of Office.js with the deployment flexibility of the EWA Namespace (e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh315812.aspx).  The REST API has limitations (no events, performance lag).  Why can't Microsoft just replace the EWA namespace with the more powerful Office.js Excel API?

Comment: We are investigating how to best serve this scenario.  So please stay tuned, and I will update this thread when we have news to share.

Comment: @Michael, that is fantastic to hear.  Or better yet, how about using Azure AD and Graph to get the sessionID of a workbook serverside (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization and https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) then allow the Office.js Excel (and Word, etc.) APIs to control that sessionID?  I think this could be very powerful (yet secure?) and would sidestep the limitations of Add-Ins.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft, any updates on this?  Is this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989152/check-if-office-js-is-loaded-outside-of-office-client  I am very interested in replacing EWA namespace with Office.js, but I don't see how yet?

Comment: hi @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft I just posted another question closely related this topic as this thread was becoming stale

Comment: @ultrasounder, I have since moved to a different team -- but hopefully someone else from the Office Extensibility team will see your question.  Just make sure it's tagged with `[office-js]`