# Execute a block only when a code has not been executed in 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, bluebird

I want to implement a promise in my code to run  `angular.bootstrap()` in `block 2` if `3 seconds` has passed and `angular.bootstrap()` in `block 1` has not been done, but only if.

I have two blocks of code:

```
// block 1:
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
    })
}

// block 2:
$(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
})
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Edit 1:** Just to clarify that it is possible that `Office.initialize` is never executed (ie, when the app is loaded in Office as an add-in). In this case, I still want to execute `angular.bootstrap` of `block 2` in 3 seconds.

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why would you need two different calls to bootstrap in the first place? Also no need to wrap `angular ready` inside jQuery ready

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44989152/702977) is why I need two different calls...

Comment: @charlietfl I just removed `angular ready` to simply the code, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout()` and `clearTimeout()` functions in JavaScript.

Function usage:

setTimeout :

```
setTimeout(function, time);`
//function is the function to execute
//time is the duration to wait (in milisecods) before executing the function
```

clearTimeout :

```
clearTimeout(id);`
//id is the id of the setTimeout block to stop from executing
```

This is how you would implement the functions into your code:

```
// block 1:
var wait = setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
          angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
          clearTimeout(wait);
      })
  })
}

// block 2:
function myFunction() {
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
}
```

Comment: Thank you... But it is possible that `Office.initialize` is never executed (when the program is loaded in Office). In this case, I still want `angular.bootstrap` of `block 2` executes in 3 seconds.

Comment: Yes. To fix that issue, you can move the `let wait = setTimeout(myFunction(), 3000);` statement to the line right before `Office.initialize` in block one

There, it is implemented in the answer now.

Comment: (please use `var` rather than `let`)... It is odd, I just implemented this, but it seems that `myFunction` will **always** be executed **immediately**.

Comment: It should be `setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);` without the parens after `myFunction`.

Comment: @jfriend00
Actually, not exactly. It works with and without the parentheses at the end, so it is just a matter of preference. I use them because it looks neater because just saying myFunction would look like calling.... a variable... So, it works both ways, not should or should-not

Comment: @SoftTimur I am not sure why this does not work, as I have used the the setTimeout function multiple times. I will further look into this though.

Comment: With the parens, it calls the function IMMEDIATELY and then passes the return value from that to the timer.  It does not wait for the timer which defeats the entire purpose.  `setTimeout()` expects you to pass it a function reference.  Passing it `myFunction()` executes that function immediately and passed `setTimeout()` the result of executing that function.  This is a common mistake in Javascript.  Only use parens after a function name when you want to execute it immediately.  If you are just passing a function reference so it can be executed later, do not use parens after it.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that! Thanks =D

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses underscorejs [once](http://underscorejs.org/#once) function. Write a function like,

```
var bootstrapInit = _.once(function(){
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Now, you can call this function in block 1, block 2 and setTimeout with 3 sec. Whichever invokes this first will execute the function and the remaining call will be dummy one.